# Is it possible that I can call another event handler inside an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have these two set of codes, one is to prompt whenever the button is clicked,

```
$('.button_class').click(function(){
    var baker_url = base_url + 'baker/baker/manage/Bread/1';
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if(answer == true){
        // if this is true, i will call an external script so that within this condition that process will be executed
    }
    else if(answer == false){
        return false; // exits
}
});
```

and then this piece of code right here is the one responsible for executing the process when the button is clicked,

```
$('.another_button_class').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var baker_url = base_url + 'baker/baker/manage/Bread/1';
        var form    = '#'+ $(this).attr('rel');
        var url     = $(form).attr('action');
        var target  = '#'+ $(form).attr('rel');
            $(target).slideUp();
            $.post(url, $(form).serialize(),function(data) {
                $(target).html(data).slideDown(function(){
                    if(data == '<div class="ok">Added</div>'){
                    setTimeout(refresh,1000)
                    c();
                    window.location = baker_url; // sets the url after refreshing
                    }
                });

            });
    });
```

in the first function, when `answer == true`, i want to execute the latter function (*the one with the process execution when button is clicked*).

Is it really possible that I can call an another function or event handler to execute its process inside another function?

Comment: External script in the sense??

Comment: by external I mean, another event handler will be called to execute certain processes.

Comment: A script is a whole execution context, and "external" means it's located in its own file. Please use the terms "function" and "(event) handler".

Comment: @Bergi , I'm sorry man, I promise I'll use the proper terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have an effect that needs to happen either when you click button #2 or when you click button #1 AND click yes in a prompt?
If so I can think of three options:

1. Name the second function and make it work if `e` is undefined; all it really does with it is prevent default. You could then call the named function from the first event.
2. Better version of 1: Make a new function that does everything except `e.preventDefault();` in the second piece of code. You could then call this from both events.
3. Use jQuery to simulate a click event for the second button, if 'yes' is selected at the first one.

**EDIT** The second one would be preferable in this case. Use the third one if you actually need the event object for something.

Comment: from what you stated above, i assume your concluding that i have two buttons but i don't. it's a single button actually with two classes..

Comment: Then in which case would the second code be executed? Exclusively when you select `yes`?

Comment: Then why can't you just place the second bit of code inside the if statement in the first bit? That would execute it when you select `yes`, right?

Comment: Actually, you're right again Mark, but what I want is that before executing the process, a confirmation will appear, oh sh*t, can you say that it is possible if i put the process itself inside the condition instead of calling it?? This just came into my mind right now.. darn.

Comment: it worked out man, i put my process execution inside the if condition, so if the answer == true, then it executes. Thanks man, guess it's fitting to accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that is what you want

```
if(answer == true){
    // if this is true, i will call an external script so that within this condition that process will be executed
    $('.another_button_class').trigger('click');
}
```

This will trigger a call the click event handlers bound on the `$('.another_button_class')` element.

---

make sure to use `e.preventDefault();` on the first click as well, or the link will be followed

Comment: it won't work out man, too bad..what happens is even if my answer == false, it will still execute the process. Supposedly, if answer == false then nothing will happen. What to do?

Comment: thanks a lot man, tried your solution but didn't quite surprise me, i needed another thing for it to work. But your answer is very great, that was really the thing I was looking for. Thanks man. :)

Comment: Great solution, thank you so much. `onkeypress  = "$('#i_field_id').trigger('blur')"` worked in my case.